# When I assign a view to class app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, crash, runtime-error

I added an extra view to project and assigned it to ViewController class. But when user wants to move to extra view with segue app crashes.

Error

```
answerBox.addTarget(nil, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged) //EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: did you add a new view or a viewcontroller?

Comment: I added a viewcontroller to main.storyboard file.